# ¿Como puedo llenar los campos de un formulario con información de una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando un proyecto en donde requiero de llenar un formulario con datos de un usuario el cual tiene su sesión activa, actualmente tengo mi código así, pero no me hace nada, espero puedan ayudarme, cabe mencionar que estoy trabajando con sesiones, por lo que requiero que los datos que me aparezcan sean del usuario que esté logueado. Saludos

```
<?php
                                    $name='.$login_session.';                                   
                                    $c=mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "");
                                    if (!$c)
                                    die( 'Error'. mysql_error() );
                                    mysql_select_db("panel",$c) or die(mysql_error());
                                    $r=mysql_query("select * from users where username=' $name '",$c) or    
                                    die(mysql_error());                                     
                                    while($user=mysql_fetch_array($r))
                                    {

                                ?> 
                                <div class="portlet-body">
                                    <div class="tab-content">
                                        <!-- PERSONAL INFO TAB -->
                                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1_1">
                                            <form role="form" action="#">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="ciudad" value="<?echo $user['name'] ?>"/>
                                                </div>                                                  
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label">email</label>
                                                    <input type="text" value="<?echo $user['email'] ?>" class="form-control"/>
                                                </div>

                                <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Hola! Lo que veo que está mal es la variable $name='.$login_session.';  debería de ser algo así: $name=$_SESSION['username']; o el nombre de la variable que guarda el username del usuario en la sesión.

Comment: PHP no evalúa las variables que están entre comillas simples `'$var'`, pero si entre comillas dobles `"$var"`; también funciona así `"UPDATE table SET user='$username' WHERE id=$pid";`. Por otro lado, la apertura corta de php `<?` debe evitarse y en su lugar siempre usar la forma estandar; y la sentencia debe terminar con punto y coma: `<?php echo $var; ?>`

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, si me funcionó. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo $user[name] ?>`

No trabajo con php y no estoy seguro pero ¿no debes abrir con '

$user[name]

sin las comillas lo tienes $user['name']

Espero haber ayudado :)